# iOS - Seam 3 Core Data - How do I repress console output?

Tags: ios, swift, seam3-coredata

I have 4-5 projects working fine using [Seam 3](https://github.com/paulw11/Seam3) I have one project though, that is spewing tons of console output. I cannot remember / know if I have turned something on/off that would create these messages. Here is a sample:

```
2020-05-07 11:19:22.204169-0400 CodeCatching[5854:771280] Cloud Sync Started
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_CHANGETYPE, t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_CHANGEDPROPERTIES, t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_ENTITYNAME, t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_QUEUED, t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_RECORDID FROM ZSM_LOCALSTORE_CHANGESETENTITY t0 WHERE ( t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_CHANGETYPE = ? OR  t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_CHANGETYPE = ?) 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0001s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0001s for 0 rows.
CoreData: sql: SELECT 0, t0.Z_PK, t0.Z_OPT, t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_CHANGETYPE, t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_CHANGEDPROPERTIES, t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_ENTITYNAME, t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_QUEUED, t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_RECORDID FROM ZSM_LOCALSTORE_CHANGESETENTITY t0 WHERE  t0.ZSM_LOCALSTORE_CHANGETYPE = ? 
CoreData: annotation: sql connection fetch time: 0.0001s
CoreData: annotation: total fetch execution time: 0.0001s for 0 rows.
2020-05-07 11:19:22.204715-0400 CodeCatching[5854:771280] Local insert/update changes detected: 0 insertedOrUpdated
[]
2020-05-07 11:19:22.204767-0400 CodeCatching[5854:771280] Local delete changes detected: 0 deleted
[]
2020-05-07 11:19:22.204830-0400 CodeCatching[5854:771280] Will attempt saving (insert/update) to the cloud 0 CKRecords []
```

How can I suppress these logs?

Answer (score 1):

In  case anyone else has this, I used [this link](https://www.avanderlee.com/debugging/core-data-debugging-xcode/) to help me out. Basically I'd forgotten that I had put these two logging commands into Xcode > editScheme > Run > variables. Price you pay for getting older.

```
-com.apple.CoreData.SQLDebug 1
-com.apple.CoreData.Logging.stderr 1
```